# JQueryUI Dialog IE9 not opening

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, dialog, internet-explorer-9

I have an aspx page that contains a dialog box defined with JQueryUI

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    minWidth: 500,
    title: 'my dialog',
    buttons: { Finished: function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }
    }
});
```

Within the page I have a button which is supposed to open the dialog

```
<button class="button" id="dialogLoader">Open</button>
```

The JavaScript for opening the dialog is

```
$('#dialogLoader').live('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#dialog').dialog("open");
    loadDialogContent();
});
```

In Chrome Firefox etc all is good but IE9 does not load the dialog, even though when debugging all code appears to execute fine.

Any Ideas

**UPDATE**

Still have this problem I have updated the code above to show that I am now utilising preventDefault(); which I thought was the cause of the problem (if the problem is indeed event bubbling). but I still have no remedy to this if this was plain HTML it would work but I fear the involvement of ASP has caused some irregularity in rendering, which unfortunately returns no error.

**UPDATE**

Could the fact that this button is within JQueryUI tabs be causing the issue in IE9?

Comment: Works for me, if I comment out the call to `loadDialogContent()`: http://jsfiddle.net/j33JK/

Comment: @TiesonT. yes I am sure this is an IE9 asp.net problem but finding the exact problem is difficult if everything appears to execute lol

Comment: Can you show the loadDialogContent method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you wrote your debug info is clean, this is just one idea. I hope this helps a little bit. attachEvent for Explorer.

```
var button = document.getElementById('dialogLoader');
if (button.addEventListener) {
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        //action
    }, true);
} else if (button.attachEvent) {
    button.attachEvent('click', function() {
        //action
    }, true);
}
```

Comment: I have used your suggestion with a little alteration I think the true in bot if conditions nees to be part of the addEventListener and attachEvent calls (let me know ifi'm wrong) and I am getting the EventListener, so I moved my execution code to replace your //action and still no joy with all executing?

Comment: You´re right about true. In that case maybe in some function that you call on action part creates the problem with IE9. Sorry that this idea is not working for you :(

Comment: I think I am entering the realm of event bubbling and this scares me lol

Comment: Could the fact that this button is within JQueryUI tabs be causing the issue in IE9?

Comment: Maybe this could help you a little bit: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7548, you can find more topics about problems with IE9